# Error "__init__ method from base class is not called" for an abstract class

Tags: python, pylint

I have

```
class A(object):
    def __init__ (self): raise NotImplementedError("A")

class B(A):
    def __init__ (self):
        ....
```

and pylint says

```
__init__ method from base class 'A' is not called
```

Obviously, I do not want to do

```
super(B, self).__init__()
```

- so what do I do?

(I tried [abc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) and got

```
Undefined variable 'abstractmethod'
```

from pylint, so that is not an option either).

Comment: I din't see where do you used abstract class. If you are trying to inherit class A in B, and want to define __init__ in B, then please use super instead. Its a wrong implementation of abc class

Comment: Could've sworn that wasn't there when I read it. Did you remember to qualify `abstractmethod` with the module name and/or `from abc import abstractmethod`?

Comment: Reported at https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3975

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `abc` works for me:

```
import abc

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
```

I get warnings, but nothing related to `abc` or the parent's `__init__` not being called:

```
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  3, 0: Invalid class name "A" (invalid-name)
C:  3, 0: Missing class docstring (missing-docstring)
R:  3, 0: Too few public methods (0/2) (too-few-public-methods)
C:  9, 0: Invalid class name "B" (invalid-name)
C:  9, 0: Missing class docstring (missing-docstring)
R:  9, 0: Too few public methods (0/2) (too-few-public-methods)
R:  3, 0: Abstract class is only referenced 1 times (abstract-class-little-used)
```

For what its worth, I'm with @holdenweb on this one. Sometimes you know better than pylint.

Comment: aha, so the solution is to use `@abc.abstractmethod` instead of `@abstractmethod`. thanks.

Comment: @sds Not really. The solution was to have `pass` instead of `raise NotImplementedError("A")` in A.__init__()

Comment: The best solution from pylint's perspective, but it's weird to call an abstract method... Abstract methods by design exist to be overridden, not called

Comment: This doesn't prevent A from being instantiated.

Answer (score 10):

Ignore pylint. It's just a program that doesn't take abstract classes into account. Be confident you are smarter than it is. Pylint is a knee brace, not a crutch.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, but I don't want to see any warnings or errors in production code.

Comment: In which case you tend towards cargo cult programming. "No warnings" is too high a standard to avoid wasting effort. However, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981978/what-makes-pylint-think-my-class-is-abstract) should give you some help.

Comment: @sds you can still disable the message locally for this specific case then

Comment: You're not giving pylint enough credit, I think: it understands abstract classes quite well (it will warn you if you forget to implement an abstract method, for example)

Comment: Quite possibly true now, so thanks for the comment, but are you sure it was true in 2014? :D Happy to incorporate suggestions in an update ...

Answer (score 1):

Defining an **empty** `__init__` as an abstract method is not very useful.

Instead, make `A` inherit from `ABC` (**AB**stract **C**lass), and use `@abstractmethod` decorator on methods that really need to be implemented by the user.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def cool_method(self):
        raise NotImplemented
```

In that way, you would effectively not be able to instantiate `A`, and at the same time, you avoid the warning. Also consider that the default `__init__` method for `A` when not implemented, would be something along the lines of:

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

So additionally, it has the advantage that it respects the `mro`, if you later want to use `A` in a multiple inheritance setup, you will not run into problems.

Comment: `Defining __init__ as an abstract method is not very useful.` = not true when you're defining an interface class and its method headers and you expect certain settings to be defined/done at object creation. Of course you could do `a = MyClass()` and then `a.my_init()` but why...

Comment: @jave.web You are right, I've corrected it to be an *empty* `__init__` instead.