# Python: suggestions how to organize a Python project. Some questions

Tags: python, coding-style

first of all thanks and i know stack overflow is full of this argument (but we can consider a review question). I have some question about to organize a Python project.

from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391879/organising-my-python-project) i had find this nice schema

```
/myproject
   /__init__.py # This makes it a Python package and importable.
   /evaluate.py # Contains the code to actually do calculations.
   /main.py # Starts the application
   /ui.py # Contains the code to make a pretty interface
```

from this [web site](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-is-init-py-used-for.htm) `__init__.py` is normally empty

my question are:

1. suppose you have a function (def foo). The foo is located in
   evaluate.py or in main.py?
2. if foo is located in `main.py` (or `evaluate.py`) what evaluate.py ( or
   main.py) contains?
3. sometimes i find `utilities.py` and/or `module.py`. What utilities.py/module.py contains?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I like to believe form follows from function. What your project does will dictate how to organize it. Your example has two components, an ui and a calculation, so there are 2 py files for these and the rest is glue to put it together. As for where your foo goes, is it a calculation foo or an ui foo. Finally, helper functions that are used everywhere are often in a common.py or utilities.py.

Comment: I don't think that example it to be taken literally. It serves to illustrate that one doesn't create modules to hold individual classes or something, but modules to contain logical groups.

Comment: Sorry, yes calculation -> evaluate

Comment: To expand on delnans comment, if it calculates stuff, evaluate.py. If it's related to showing things to the user, ui.py. If it's related to starting everything up or cleanup, main.py.

Comment: i have not clear main.py. Someone know a good link to look inside main.py? thanks

Comment: Typically in `main` you parse command line arguments, read the environment, parse configuration files, open input files, connect to servers etc., then hand off the work to the actual processing modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my coding style:
`main.py`: always do simple things about initialize variables from environ outside and load config file. And wrap actual logic things. For example:

```
from evaluate import actual_things
def run():
    ...
    actual_things()
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
    load_from_config()
    run()
```

Q: sometimes i find utilities.py and/or module.py. What utilities.py/module.py contains?
A:`utilities.py`: or `utils.py` often is helper. Such as encode and decode, encrypt etc.

Q:if foo is located in main.py (or evaluate.py) what evaluate.py ( or main.py) contains?
A:You mush point out what foo do and according to the function of foo, we locate foo to somewhere. If foo is a business relatively function, foo should be located in evaluate.py.

Q:suppose you have a function (def foo). The foo is located in evaluate.py or in main.py?
A:See above.

At last, I think the best approach to know is to learn a project overall. You will know what QA can't help.